# compute $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

> A continuous function $f:[0,1)\to [0,\infty)$ satisfies $f(x/2+1/2) = f(x)+1$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and $f(1-x) = 1/f(x)$ for all $x\in (0,1)$. Compute $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

> This is question 11 from [this problem set](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ex46wang/Weekly/2019/A6.pdf).

$f(x)$ cannot be zero for any $x>0$ since otherwise $f(1-x) = 1/f(x)$ would not hold. My first thought is to use some sort of substitution (e.g. $x\mapsto 1-x$, which gives $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{f(x)}$ ). It might be true that $f(x)+f(1/2-x)=1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1/2$ (or we could extend $f$ to negative $x$ if necessary). $f(0)+f(1/2) = 1$ follows from $f(1/2) = f(0) + 1$ and $f(1/2) = 1/f(1/2)\Rightarrow f(1/2)^2 = 1\Rightarrow f(1/2) = 1\Rightarrow f(0)=0$.

We know $f(1/2-x)=f(1-(1/2+x)) = 1/f(1/2+x) = 1/(f(2x)+1).$ So we need to equivalently show that $f(x)+1/f(x+1/2) = 1,$ or $f(x+1/2) = 1/(1-f(x)).$
However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Then it might be useful to come up with recursive formulas for an integral and use that to find $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$. It might be useful to split $[0,1]$ into carefully chosen subintervals.

Comment: This has the flavour of a [tag:contest-math] question, and I notice that your previous (at least) three questions all have this tag. Our policy, which wasn't rigorously adhered to in your previous questions, is for contest questions to cite the contest that they came from, so that people know it's not from a current contest. Which contest does this question come from?

Comment: @TheoBendit I have added the source of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that $f(x)+f(1/2-x)=1$ whenever $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$:

\begin{align*}
f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)&=\frac{1}{f(1-x)}+\frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{2}+x\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{f(1-2x)+1}+\frac{1}{f(2x)+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(2x)}+1}+\frac{1}{f(2x)+1}\\
&=\frac{f(2x)}{1+f(2x)}+\frac{1}{f(2x)+1}\\
&=1 \, .
\end{align*}

It then follows that

\begin{align*}\int_0^{1/2} f(x) \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{1/2} \left[f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)\right] \, dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{1/2} 1 \, dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

and so

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx &= \int_0^{1/2} f(x) \, dx +\int_{1/2}^1 f(x) \, dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4} + \int_{1/2}^1 f(x) \, dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f\left(\frac{u+1}{2}\right) \, du\\
&=\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \left[f(u)+1\right] \, du\\
&=\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f(u) \, du
\end{align*}

meaning that we have $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \frac{3}{2}$.

---

Incidentally, $f$ is uniquely defined, and is a rather interesting function: e.g., it maps the dyadic rationals in $[0,1)$ surjectively to all rationals in $\left[0,\infty\right)$.